# UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext value pass to CGContextRef is not working?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

```
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
UIBezierPath *path=[self pathFromPoint:currentPoint 
                               toPoint:currentPoint];

CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
CGContextAddPath(currentContext, path.CGPath);
CGContextDrawPath(currentContext, kCGPathFill);
drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

In the above code `CGContextRef currentContext`  created of `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` and pass it to  `CGContextBeginPath CGContextAddPath CGContextDrawPath`  currentContext has parameter to them its not working for me!  When i am doing `touchMovie`.

When i pass directly `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` in place of `currentContext` its working for me.  I want to know why its like that?

@All Please Advice me for this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `currentContext` is no longer the current context after you start an image context:

```
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
// Now the image context is the new current context.
```

So you should invert these two lines:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

**Edit**

As Nicolas has noted, you should end the image context when you no longer need it:

```
drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); // Add this line.
```

**Edit**

Also notice that you are setting a **stroke** color but drawing with the **fill** command.

So you should call the appropriate color method instead:

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Furthermore, you should end the image context when you don't need it anymore in order to restore the graphic stack in its previous state:
`UIGraphicsEndImageContext();`

Comment: i find another issue on this!  i can't able to set color to this CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(currentContext, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);  if i set it to red it's still drawing black!

Answer (score 1):

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` creates a new context and sets it at the current context.
So you should do

`CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`

*after* `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. Otherwise, you fetch a context, and this context is immediately superseded by `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`.